# Extract a word between brackets and replace it in a sentence

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

so let's say i have this sentence

`It's {raining|snowing|cold} outside`

What I want is to randomly extract a word between the brackets, which i did with `awk -vRS="}" -vFS="|" '{print $2}'` (still working to extract them randomly). The output usually is the second word, in our case `snowing`.

Thing is that the output is only `snowing`, and the actual output i want is something like `It's snowing outside`, so how do I extract any word from the brackets and replace with only one word.

Comment: If you want to randomly select one out of three words, why choose such a complicated way to do it? Make an array of three words and use `RANDOM % 3` to select one of them.

Comment: That sentence was just an example, in reality i have a way lot more sentences that contains such words inside brackets, and I managed to extract only the second words, which it shouldn't be a problem anyway, I asked about randomising out of curiosity

Comment: I would parse the sentences to produce the arrays, then pick (by randomization or other means).

Comment: Fair enough, and how do I replace the words inside the brackets with only one word extracted from there

Comment: You're trying to take a shortcut. Perhaps it exists but I would first write a parser for the format that you're handling to get an array of data and from that select one word. If you only need _one_ word and it doesn't matter which one, you could [tag:regex] away the optional words.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to rewrite a string by finding and replacing a part of it, regex is suitable

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub pick_one { 
    my ($pattern) = @_; 
    my @choices = split /\|/, $pattern; 
    return $choices[int rand @choices]; 
}

my $sentence = q(It's {raining|snowing|cold} outside); 

$sentence =~ s/\{ ( [^}]+ ) \}/pick_one($1)/ex; 

say $sentence;
```

That `/e` modifier makes it evaluate the replacement side as code, and the produced value is then used as the replacement. So there we run a sub in which the choosing happens. Having this in a sub is a good way for later refinements/changes, implemented in the sub.

An element of the array `@choices` is selected using [rand](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand). An expression for its upper bound is evaluated in the scalar context so we can directly use the `@choices` array since then its length ends up being used.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "It's {raining|snowing|cold} outside" |\
  perl -pe 's/\{(.*?)\}/(split("[|]",$1)[rand(3)]/e'
```

or for arbitrary number of weather conditions:

```
echo "It's {raining|snowing|cold} outside" |\
  perl -pe 's/\{(.*?)\}/@a=split("[|]",$1); $a[rand(@a)]/e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { srand() }
match($0,/\{[^}]+}/) {
    wordList = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    numWords = split(wordList,words,/[|]/)
    wordNr = int(rand() * numWords + 1)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) words[wordNr] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
It's snowing outside

$ awk -f tst.awk file
It's cold outside
```

See `rand()` (and `srand()`) at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Numeric-Functions for details on it's randomness.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting solution is to (ab)use Perl's [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) function to generate a list of possible combinations. The caveat is that you cannot use glob meta characters in the string. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

my $str = "It's {freaking|fudging} {raining|snowing|cold} outside";

$str =~ s#({[^}]+})#$1 =~ s/\|/,/gr#ge;   # replace | with , inside curly braces
my @list = glob $str;
print Dumper \@list;

say "Our random string: " . $list[ int rand(@list) ];
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'It\'s freaking raining outside',
          'It\'s freaking snowing outside',
          'It\'s freaking cold outside',
          'It\'s fudging raining outside',
          'It\'s fudging snowing outside',
          'It\'s fudging cold outside'
        ];
Our random string: It's fudging cold outside
```

Comment: Witty!  Minor simplification: ```$str =~ s#({.+?})#$1 =~ s/\|/,/gr#ge```

Comment: @sizif I'm familiar with the non-greedy quantifier, but I prefer to use `[^}]+` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With  [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) it is a one-liner:

```sh
echo "It's {raining|snowing|cold} outside" | \
jq -rR --argjson rand $RANDOM 'gsub("{(?<words>[^}]+)}"; .words | split("|") | .[$rand % length])'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "It's {raining|snowing|cold} outside"|awk -F"[{|}]" -v w="$(shuf -i 2-4 -n 1)" '{print $1$w$NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain `bash`, without using any external command:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (.*)\{([^}]*)}(.*) ]]; then
        IFS='|' read -ra words <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        line=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${words[RANDOM%${#words[*]}]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < file
```